# Portfolio construction and different rebalancing periods in R

Tags: r, finance, portfolio

I would like to calculate monthly value weighted returns for a portfolio that is quarterly rebalanced according to certain characteristics. I am new to R and would very much appreciate your help.

The portfolio construction rules are the following (quite similar to Fama and French's (1993) HML factor portfolio.
(1) Rank stocks by 6 months lagged/prior book-to-market ratio (Lagged_BtM). (t-6)
(2) The 30% stocks with the highest Lagged_BtM respresent the "high" portfolio and the 30% stocks with the lowest Lagged_BtM are the "low" portfolio.
(3) Rebalance the portfolio every 3 months (every quarter) according to the rules in (2). e.g. buy the top 30% stocks in terms of Lagged_BtM on 2000-01-31, hold them for 3 months & calculate the portfolio return for each of those 3 months. On 2000-04-31 rank stocks by Lagged_BtM again and buy/adjust the portfolio according to the rules in (2). And so on until a specified end date in the data set. (t, t+3, t+6 etc.)
(4) Calculate value weighted monthly returns. Weigh each firm's return by its market capitalization (Market_Cap) at the portfolio formation time. To use the example above: Consider Market_Cap on 2000-01-31 and then again on 2000-04-31 and so on.

My data set looks like this:

```
Name = c(rep("Company X", 12), rep("Company Y", 12), rep("Company Z", 12))
Date = rep(rev(seq(as.Date("2000-02-01"), as.Date("2001-01-01"), by = "1 month") - 1), 3)
Market_Cap = c(runif(12, 35000, 40000), runif(12, 5000, 8000), runif(12, 20000, 22000)) # Market capitalization
Book_to_Market = c(runif(12, 0.2, 1), runif(12, 0.9, 2), runif(12, 0.6, 1.5))
Total_Return_Index = c(runif(12, 19, 25), runif(12, 74, 82), runif(12, 4, 11))
stocks = data.frame(Name, Date, Market_Cap, Book_to_Market, Total_Return_Index)
```

Then I add some columns that help me with my calculation. Probably not need for someone who knows R.

```
# Add columns to simplify calculation
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # Not sure if I used this

stocks = stocks %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Monthly.Return = log(lag(Total_Return_Index, 1) / Total_Return_Index)) %>% # Calculate 1 month (log) returns
  mutate(Weighted.Return = Monthly.Return * Market_Cap) %>% # Add column to help me calculate value weighted returns (returns weighted by Market_Cap)
  mutate(Lagged_BtM = lead(Book_to_Market, n = 3)) %>% # Add 3 months lagged Book_to_Market (6 months in real data)
  mutate(Quarterly.Return = log(lag(Total_Return_Index, 3) / Total_Return_Index)) %>% # Add quarterly return, used later
  mutate(q.Weighted.Return = Quarterly.Return * Market_Cap) # Quarterly value weighted return, used later

stocks = with(stocks, subset(stocks, Lagged_BtM != "NA" & Weighted.Return != "NA")) # Remove NA from Lagged_BtM and Weighted.Return
```

Then my data frame looks like this:

```
        Name       Date Market_Cap Book_to_Market Total_Return_Index Monthly.Return Weighted.Return Lagged_BtM
1  Company X 2000-11-30  35565.061      0.4094885           22.24248    0.012044044       428.34715  0.4231916
2  Company X 2000-10-31  39544.379      0.8467753           24.22646   -0.085441292     -3378.72281  0.8682684
3  Company X 2000-09-30  38306.471      0.8340233           20.20816    0.181358708      6947.21209  0.7640378
4  Company X 2000-08-31  36791.679      0.4231916           22.87716   -0.124052523     -4564.10060  0.7609808
5  Company X 2000-07-31  37414.159      0.8682684           19.47549    0.160982536      6023.02618  0.7534791
6  Company X 2000-06-30  37724.365      0.7640378           24.50530   -0.229732765     -8666.52262  0.7444255
7  Company X 2000-05-31  39639.062      0.7609808           21.36683    0.137049816      5432.52619  0.8661182
8  Company X 2000-04-30  37258.858      0.7534791           21.47190   -0.004905545      -182.77501  0.7011865
9  Company Y 2000-11-30   7509.425      1.7420568           74.26786    0.032263995       242.28404  1.5831691
10 Company Y 2000-10-31   5872.622      1.0926830           75.19581   -0.012417092       -72.92088  1.7423244
..       ...        ...        ...            ...                ...            ...             ...        ...
Variables not shown: Quarterly.Return (dbl), q.Weighted.Return (dbl)
```

Finally I calulate my MONTHLY rebalanced portfolios and add the HML portfolio:

```
## Create monthly rebalanced portfolios
# Create portfolio with low lagged book-to-market ratio
low.BtM = stocks %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(Lagged_BtM < quantile(Lagged_BtM, 0.3)) %>% # Bottom 30% stocks in terms of lagged book-to-market
  summarise(
    n.low.BtM = length(Weighted.Return), # Number of stocks per portfolio
    return.low.BtM = mean(Weighted.Return) / mean(Market_Cap) # Monthly return
  )

# Create portfolio with high lagged book-to-market ratio
high.BtM = stocks %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(Lagged_BtM > quantile(Lagged_BtM, 0.7)) %>% # Top 30% stocks in terms of lagged book-to-market
  summarise(
    n.high.BtM = length(Weighted.Return),
    return.high.BtM = mean(Weighted.Return) / mean(Market_Cap)
  )

# Combine portfolios in one data frame, add high minus low portfolio (HML)
Portfolios = cbind(low.BtM, high.BtM[ , 2:3])
Portfolios$HML = Portfolios$return.high.BtM - Portfolios$return.low.BtM # Add HML portfolio (return.high.BtM - return.low.BtM)
```

What I get is this, which might (not sure) be correct for a MONTHLY rebalanced portfolio.

```
        Date n.low.BtM return.low.BtM n.high.BtM return.high.BtM         HML
1 2000-04-30         1   -0.004905545          1     0.036513834  0.04141938
2 2000-05-31         1    0.037053475          1     0.017815062 -0.01923841
3 2000-06-30         1   -0.229732765          1     0.051991828  0.28172459
4 2000-07-31         1    0.160982536          1     0.015922870 -0.14505967
5 2000-08-31         1   -0.124052523          1    -0.009022466  0.11503006
6 2000-09-30         1    0.181358708          1    -0.033899042 -0.21525775
7 2000-10-31         1   -0.085441292          1    -0.012417092  0.07302420
8 2000-11-30         1    0.012044044          1     0.032263995  0.02021995
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to calculate monthly returns for a QUARTERLY rebalanced portfolio. If anything is unclear I will be happy to edit it. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Certainly this attempt is wrong...

```
## Create quarterly rebalanced portfolios
stocks = with(stocks, subset(stocks, Lagged_BtM != "NA" & q.Weighted.Return != "NA")) # Remove NA from Lagged_BtM and q.Weighted.Return

# Create portfolio with low lagged book-to-market ratio
low.BtM = stocks %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(Lagged_BtM < quantile(Lagged_BtM, 0.3)) %>%
  summarise(
    n.low.BtM = length(q.Weighted.Return),
    return.low.BtM = mean(q.Weighted.Return) / mean(Market_Cap)
  )
# etc.
```

Comment: Why group_by(Date)? If you want to re-balance by quarter shouldn't you use `group_by(year_qtr)` ? where :

Comment: where : `year_qtr = lubridate::quarter(Date,with_year=TRUE)`. I am pretty new to finance so might not completely understand your problem here.